# How to calculate and convert floating number to binary value?

Tags: ios, swift, binary, trigonometry

I am working on a binary calculator app in iOS swift/SwiftUI, normal calculation are working fine in that calculator as

1. I take input in binary and convert binary input to Int
2. calculate its (Int) result
3. convert result back to the binary and show that converted result on screen.

The problem occurred in the trigonometry functions like sin, cos, tan, sinh, cosh, tanh,
Input binary `101 = 5` in decimal. Now

`sin(5)`

result is:

```
degree is -0.95892427466 
radina is 0.08715574274
```

These values are in the floating number, how to convert these values in the binary number accurately in swift?
As you can see these values are in negative and also in the floating points.

My code is right now

```
 let parser = MathParser(enableImpliedMultiplication: true)
```

MathParser is the library that I am using for caculation

```
expression = sin(5)*sin(5)
separator = *
    let components = expression.components(separatedBy: seprator)        
        if components.count > 1 {
            // Get the two binary strings
            var newString = ""
            for component in components {
                if component.contains("sin") || component.contains("cos") || component.contains("tan") ||
                    component.contains("sinh") || component.contains("cosh") || component.contains("tanh") {
                    // I want to do work here

                } else {
// Here I am doing some binary calculations like 101*101 (base 2) = 5*5 (base 10) and that's working fine
                    newString += "\(binaryStringToInt(component) ?? 0) \(seprator)"
                }
            }
            newString.removeLast(seprator.count)
            let value = parser.parse("\(newString)")?.value
            return value
        }
```

These are the helper methods

```
// Function to convert a binary string to an integer
func binaryStringToInt(_ binaryString: String) -> Int? {
    return Int(binaryString, radix: 2)
}

// Function to convert an integer to a binary string
func intToBinaryString(_ value: Int) -> String {
    return String(value, radix: 2)
}
```

Don't get confuse with the expression and separator, its the actual code in under process. I need to do these things in later, but right now my problem is
Convert floating or Negative values in the binary number.

Comment: It depends on which floating point format you want to use. You probably want [IEEE754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) but you can't mix and match integer binary arithmetic with floating point arithmetic.

Comment: So what do you suggest about it? I only want to calculate the trigonometry functions for binary and show result in binary...! My input is in binary. I can give you more insight, if you need it.

Comment: You can't represent a floating point number in simple binary.  Like 0001=1  and 0010 = 2, but if you want to represent a floating point number (and you can only represent an approximation of the real number), then you need to select some format.  For example [16 bit half precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-precision_floating-point_format) uses 1 bit for the sign, 5 bits for the exponent and 11 bits for the significand. If you want your calculator to support floating point then you can't really have it display binary - It is too difficult for humans to read.

Comment: For example, if you switch Apple's calculator for the Mac into "programmer mode" you can only perform integer operations.  If you use "scientific" mode you can use floating point operations but you can't see the result in binary.